# AD B2C Keep Password from Expiring on New User

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api, identity-experience-framework

We're trying to create a user in Azure AD B2C (cloud tenant, not local) via the C# library. I cannot log in with the new user; it's saying the password has expired. From the AD B2C Sign-in log:

[image]

However, I'm creating them with password expiration disabled like so:

```cs
PasswordProfile passwordProfile = GetPasswordProfile(password);
var newB2cUser = new User
{
    Id = id,
    MailNickname = id,
    UserPrincipalName = $"{id}@{tenant}",
    GivenName = claims.FirstName,
    Surname = claims.LastName,
    DisplayName = displayName,
    AccountEnabled = true,
    PasswordProfile = passwordProfile,
    PasswordPolicies = "DisablePasswordExpiration,DisableStrongPassword",
    Identities = new List<ObjectIdentity>
    {
        new ObjectIdentity
        {
            SignInType = "emailAddress",
            IssuerAssignedId = claims.Email,
            Issuer = tenant
        }
    }
};

User createdB2cUser = await this.GraphServiceClient.Users.Request().AddAsync(newB2cUser);
```

...and with the password profile created like this:

```cs
private static PasswordProfile GetPasswordProfile(string password)
{
    var passwordProfile = new PasswordProfile
    {
        Password = password,
        ForceChangePasswordNextSignIn = false,
        ForceChangePasswordNextSignInWithMfa = false
    };

    return passwordProfile;
}
```

We've used code like the above to create users all the time that need to reset their password on login. Now we need to create a user with a preset password that won't immediately expire (e.g., seeding a test environment). I added what I thought were the correct password policies and password profile above. What's going on?

Answer (score -1):

I can see nothing wrong with the code sample you provided. But did you try achieving the same goal using Graph API directly? Just to understand what is going on and where the fault may be. You can use GraphExplorer: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer

Invoke a POST request to the https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users endpoint with the similar JSON to see whether you face the same issue.

```
{
    "id": "fcaba916-17b0-4d88-84ea-03371d55067a",
    "mailNickname": "MelissaD",
    "userPrincipalName": "MelissaD@contoso.onmicrosoft.com",
    "givenName": "Melissa",
    "surname": "Darrow",
    "displayName": "Melissa Darrow",
    "accountEnabled": true,
    "passwordPolicies": "DisablePasswordExpiration,DisableStrongPassword",
    "passwordProfile": {
        "password": "da413e48-180d-1945-6025-d7e5947711ed",
        "forceChangePasswordNextSignIn": false,
        "forceChangePasswordNextSignInWithMfa": false
    },
    "identities": [
        {
            "signInType": "emailAddress",
            "issuer": "yourissuer",
            "issuerAssignedId": "email"
        }
    ]
}
```

Try to simulate the request body exactly as Graph Client does to know what is going on behind the scenes.

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with the request or I would have gotten an error back, no? The NET client maps directly onto the request params.

Comment: Can you please post one sample request JSON idenitical to the one that results in this problem? I want to attempt to replicate the issue on my side.

Comment: We moved on and found another approach (require initial password reset for seeded users). No time to mess with this anymore I'm afraid. Will keep this question open in case there's a trick to making this work, would love to see if so. Thank you anyway.